# Debug transform bean to mock

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Is there any library that allows you to transform an object instance at runtime to some mock library instructions like mockito?

For instance, it might be a list of beans returning from a hibernate query.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Of course you can mock or spy every object instance with mockito. But is that your question?

Comment: I try to explain better. Imagine you wrote a piece of software and a bug happens. At runtime you have all the paramenters and class fields setted, and a method throws an exceptio. What i'm asking is if there's some libraries or way to use mockito to automatically generate mockito instructions to create mocks representing the same situation of the bug i wrote above :)